# Cosmos DB query doesn't return all results

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

### Scenario 1:

One of the following:

- Cosmos DB query doesn't return **all expected results** in one query.
- Cosmos DB query returns different **result count** for the same query.

This behavior could be seen in the following cases:

1. On the Portal, executing a query with TOP, e.g. SELECT TOP 10 but the returned results has less than 10 elements as expected.
2. On the Portal, executing the same query, but every time there is a different set of results. The result sets are different but some results are covered by other result. E.g. considering a query with the expected results of [C, O, S, M, O, S]. In the 1st execution, the results is: [C, O, S]. In the 2nd execution, the result is [C, O, S, M, O]. The 2nd result covers the 1st results.
3. Using query REST API, the query returns less results than running the same query on the Portal.

### Scenario 2:

- Cosmos DB query returns **different results (not result count)** for the same query

Answer (score 0):

### Scenario 1

The behavior is due to the query cannot be completed within one page. There could be a few reasons:

- The collection doesn't have enough provisioned RUs to accommodate current traffic going to the collection and the current query is affected.
- The query is significantly extensive.

In these cases, the query splits the results set into multiple pages. Therefore, in order to get all the results, we need to iterate through all the pages until the end.

How to iterate through the pages depends on the way to run the query.

- In Portal, when a query has more than one page of results, you should see "Load More" link available. Clicking on this link will move to the next result page.
- Using the SDK, the SDK has the support for paging behind the scene. Examples for .NET SDK can be found [in the sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-dotnet/blob/master/samples/code-samples/Queries/Program.cs#L675). Other SDK works in a similar way.
- Using REST API, you would need to get the continuation token value in the current query response header, and then set it in the request header for the next query. The header name is **x-ms-continuation**. More details can be found in [the Querying resources article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/querying-cosmosdb-resources-using-the-rest-api#pagination-of-query-results).

### Scenario 2

This behavior is due to there is write traffic going to the account. Therefore, the query result is different for each query.